# GetItem from DynamoDB using range key in java

Tags: java, java-8, amazon-dynamodb

I have created a dynamodb table named `orders`. My partition key(Hash key) is `orderId` and sort key(Range key) is `storeId`.

I am able to put the records in my table using both the keys. But now **I have a requirement where I need to fetch all the values form database** with the `storeId` which can be a list of values. However, I do not see any api in java that fetches the value using **range key**. Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to fetching data from DynamoDB, you have two methods at your disposal; `query` and `scan`.

The `query` operation is for when you want to look up an item by it's primary key. In your example, that means you know the `orderId` and `storeId` (or just the `orderId`)

The `scan` operation is for when you want to fetch data using an attribute other than the partition key.  This is what you'd need to use to fetch items by `storeId`.

However, you'll likely see the advice to avoid a `scan` operation whenever possible.  This is because the `scan` operation must read the entire database to fetch the items of interest.  To avoid this, you could introduce a global secondary index on the `storeId` field, which would allow you to fetch items by `storeId` using the `query` operation.

Comment: That's one genuine solution. However, I would like to ask can I add sortkey as global secondary index and then define projection as keys_only? since it is still a key element